# Can a CROSS JOIN be "implicitly LATERAL"?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, lateral-join

Assume the following, rather simplistic database:

```
CREATE TABLE test_table(
  name TEXT,
  data JSONB
);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES ('name1', '{"a": 1, "b": 2}'), ('name2', '{"c": 3, "d": 4, "e": 5}');
```

so we have the following table:

```
# SELECT * FROM test_table ;
 name  |           data
-------+--------------------------
 name1 | {"a": 1, "b": 2}
 name2 | {"c": 3, "d": 4, "e": 5}
(2 rows)
```

Now I've seen a query like this:

```
# SELECT * FROM test_table CROSS JOIN JSONB_EACH(test_table.data);
```

returning the following result:

```
 name  |           data           | key | value
-------+--------------------------+-----+-------
 name1 | {"a": 1, "b": 2}         | a   | 1
 name1 | {"a": 1, "b": 2}         | b   | 2
 name2 | {"c": 3, "d": 4, "e": 5} | c   | 3
 name2 | {"c": 3, "d": 4, "e": 5} | d   | 4
 name2 | {"c": 3, "d": 4, "e": 5} | e   | 5
(5 rows)
```

My problem is that I do not understand what happens here.  On the one
hand, this looks like a `LATERAL` join, since the right-hand side of
`JOIN` refers to the left-hand one, and the result is perfectly
logical.  On the other hand, the manual says this:

> (Without `LATERAL`, each sub-`SELECT` is evaluated independently and so
>   cannot cross-reference any other `FROM` item.)

and this:

> The column source table(s) must be `INNER` or `LEFT` joined to the `LATERAL`
>   item […]

(see [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html)), and of course the `CROSS JOIN` does not return *n*×*m*
rows (as [this page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM) says).

My question is: does the result of the query above not contradict the
manual?  If not, does that mean that `JSONB_EACH` is somehow treated
specially?  (That I would find surprising.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *If not, does that mean that JSONB_EACH is somehow treated specially?*

Yes it is, because it's a table function (aka "set returning function")

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL)

> Table functions appearing in FROM can also be preceded by the key word LATERAL, **but for functions the key word is optional**; the function's arguments can contain references to columns provided by preceding FROM items in any case.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Comment: It is optional for not just table functions, but actually for any functions. Postgres can even optimize to not use lateral at all if you actually don't refer to any of the previous table(s) and/or column(s) -- which is a bit annoying in some special cases i.e. https://rextester.com/WSZR96195

Comment: so, may i inquire: ¿Can I understand or see a table functions as a kind of lateral subquery?