# How to query JSON Column in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

My table name is participant_preference and the column name is 'value' and the JSON is in the column as below,

```
{
  "DiaryUsers": [
    {
      "UserId": "HUGWFJJ6",
      "IsDiaryVisible": false,
      "ParticipantName": "Dr. Mckenzie, Alistair G [SP000024]",
      "Status": "A"
    },
    {
      "UserId": "HUV65PV1",
      "IsDiaryVisible": true,
      "ParticipantName": "Dr. Mckenzie, Alistair G [SP000024]",
      "Status": "A"
    }
  ]
}
```

I need help to query UserId for specific id i.e UserId=HUV65PV1 and expecting to get only this users data from sql query.

My database is postgres sql.

Please let me know if I missed any details.

Answer (score 2):

Use `jsonb_array_elements` in a `CROSS JOIN` to access the array elements, e.g.

```
SELECT e.* FROM t
CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(col->'DiaryUsers') e
WHERE e->>'UserId' = 'HUV65PV1';
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/p7jd5pY6)

Comment: `CROSS JOIN LATERAL`, though 'lateral' is redundant,  might be more [clear to read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58280136/can-a-cross-join-be-implicitly-lateral).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Jim, do I need to use exact query or do I need to any changes?

Comment: @MadhuManohar the query works fine just like this. Of course, you have to change the table and column names to fit your environment ;)

Comment: @Stefanov.sm you're totally right, although it is correct like this, leaving lateral out might be misleading. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it using [`jsonb_path_query_array`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) :

```
select jsonb_path_query_array(col->'DiaryUsers', '$[*] ? (@.UserId == "HUGWFJJ6")') as user
from participant_preference 
where col->'DiaryUsers' @> '[{"UserId":"HUGWFJJ6"}]';
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/P6kxPVGS)

Comment: I replaced "col" to my column name executed and got below error. please guide me

ERROR:  operator does not exist: text -> unknown
LINE 1: select jsonb_path_query_array(value->'DiaryUsers', '$[*] ? (...
                                           ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. 

SQL state: 42883
Character: 36

Comment: The error message say that your column is defined as text not as jsonb, it need to be casted https://dbfiddle.uk/LLTwoSj5